# how to print all of the sqlite database stored on the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, dump

I'm developing an application for ios which uses sqlite3
I need to debug a bit on my device and I'd love to have function on my code to print out everything present on the sqlite3 database I'm using. any idea?

it's pretty annoying every time to use "phonedisk" and read it manually, I'm wasting a lot of time in this way
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eather you use sqlite command line tool or a other sqlite database tool for debugging the database of the simulator or you have to write you own method which selects all data from all tables and prints them out.